# Conversion of String with emoticon unicode format to String with single character emoticon

Tags: c#, unicode

I am trying to convert a `String` object containing a string representing an emoticon's Unicode format into a `String` with the same emoticon represented by the Unicode as its only character, e.g. converting `"\u1F34E"` to .

I attempted the following under the supposition the string's escape sequence would be properly processed:

```
String str = "\u1F34E";
Console.WriteLine("'{0}' to '{1}'", str, str.ToCharArray()[0]);
```

Output:

```
'\u1F34E' to '\'
```

Outputting the string directly to a text file yields the same result, so it is not just the debugger I am using. I am unsure what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I realize my original question was not clear; my intent was to have a properly formatted UTF-16 string with a UTF-32 unicode within a string, as an API I was sending this value to required this formatting. I have successfully resolved the problem with the following:

```
String str = "1F34E"; //removed \u with prior parsing
int unicode_utf32 = int.Parse(stdemote.Unicode, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
String unicode_utf16_str = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(unicode_utf32);
Console.WriteLine("'{0}' to '{1}'", str, unicode_utf16_str);
```

Comment: Note that code shown in the post **does not** produce output you claim it does. It is very unclear if you are looking how to represent non-basic-plane emoj characters in C# string *or* you actually have representation from somewhere else coming with format similar to C# strings and you want to convert that to C# string *or* you have no idea how non-basic-plane Unicode code points represented in .Net strings and asking about that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not what it seems

```
string str = "\u1F34E";
```

*.Net* uses using *UTF-16* to encode its strings. This means two bytes (16-bit) are used to represent one *Unicode Code Point*. Which in turn makes the *Unicode* `\u` escape sequence actually `U+0000` to `U+FFFF` (16-bit) or for the extended version  `U+00000000` to `U+FFFFFFFF` (32-bit)

The emoji , uses a high code point `0001F34E` so will need to encode it as a surrogate pair, two *UTF-16* characters `"\uD83C\uDF4E"` or combined as
`"\U0001F34E"` <sup>1</sup>

**Example**

```
string str = "\uD83C\uDF4E";
// or
string str = "\U0001F34E"
```

If you goal is to separate actual text elements apposed to characters, you could make use of `StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator`

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ToElements(string source)
{
   var enumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(source);
   while (enumerator.MoveNext())
      yield return enumerator.GetTextElement();
}
```

<sub>***Note** : My use of terminology might not be most common or accurate, if you think it can be tightened up feel free to edit*</sub>

---

<sup>1</sup> Thanks to [Mark Tolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235698/mark-tolonen) for pointing out that the Unicode *escape sequence* actually supports both 16bit and 32bit variants `\uXXXX` and `\UXXXXXXXX` more information can be found in a blog post by Jon Skeet [Strings in C# and .NET](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Strings)

Comment: Thank you, this was precisely the problem I was having. I used the code in the above edited original post to solve the problem.

Comment: C# allows `\U0001F34E` escape codes so you don't have to manually build surrogates.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I am extremely grateful for this comment, ill try and formulate an update soon

Comment: No problem.  Here's a reference: https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Strings

Comment: @MarkTolonen, once again thanks for your input, updated and attributed